# How to remove or disable a fundamental toolbar from ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcobjects, arcgis-10.4

I don't want hide a toolbar, rather I need to prevent a user from using some fundamental toolbars (not custom ones).

I have been reading anything about a file '.mxd' or '.mdx', but it's not clear to me yet.

I use ArcObjects SDK.

Comment: No, you cannot disable a builtin toolbar. You could try an event interface and hide the toolbar as soon as customization is done though. Have a look at http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0023000000n7000000 which should be fired when a user customizes the document.

Comment: Have you found the interface to turn off a toolbar? I can only see how to turn one on not turn one off.. When you do can you tell me? I would be very interested to see how you do it.

Comment: I only can hide an especific fundamental toolbar, or all at time. So when I can disable one, I'll post it here.

Comment: Ah, the lengths we go to prevent our users from messing everything up!

Answer (score 2):

To hide all toolbars.

```
IApplication m_aplication = ArcMap.Application;
m_aplication.Document.CommandBars.HideAllToolbars();
```

To hide an especific toolbar by name.

```
ICommandBar ToolsBar = GetToolbarByName(m_aplication, "esriArcMapUI.BrowseToolBar");
ToolsBar.Dock(esriDockFlags.esriDockTop);
```

```
public static ICommandBar GetToolbarByName(IApplication mapplication, String toolbarName)// Example: "esriArcMapUI.StandardToolBar"
        {
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandBars commandBars = mapplication.Document.CommandBars;
            ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UID barID = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.UIDClass();
            barID.Value = toolbarName;
            ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandItem commandItem = commandBars.Find(barID, false, false);
            if (commandItem != null && commandItem.Type == ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.esriCommandTypes.esriCmdTypeToolbar)
            {
                return (ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.ICommandBar)commandItem;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
```

Comment: Does this disable them, or just hide them?